# Django & AJAX to show DB objects upon user's input submission

Tags: django, ajax

I'm pretty new in the Web development world, have been using Django so far.

I've been trying to figure out how to render data back to page after clicking on a submit button, so I see I'll need to use AJAX for that purpose.

I've created a very simple app just to understand the basics of AJAX.
However, googling, I couldn't really find a basic straight-forward implementation so I kinda got lost...

What I'm trying to achieve:

I have a model called Country:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=35)
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    capital = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

And a super simple main page that asks the user to insert some country name.

The idea is to bring to the page all the info from the DB.
So it would look like this:
[image]

**Main page HTML body:**

```
<body>
    <h2><em>Please type a country name:</em></h2><br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="get_info" method="post">
            {{ form }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input id="submit_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Get info">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from country_trivia import forms


def main_page(request):
    get_info_form = forms.GetInfo()
    return render(request, 'country_trivia/index.html', {'form': get_info_form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms


class GetInfo(forms.Form):
    country_name = forms.CharField(label="")
```

I've seen some examples using forms, but I'm not even sure if it's needed, as I've seen some other examples that count on 'onclick' even listeners, then "grab" the text in the search field and pass it via AJAX...

How should I build my AJAX object for that simple purpose, and how should I integrate it?

Do I need to use forms at all?
I don't post anything to DB, just query it and print out data...

Thanks!!

Comment: What Ajax have you tried?  This is pretty straight forward. Should be able to watch a 3 minute YouTube video.  You do not need a form.

Comment: There are too many videos and tutorials that show different approaches and implementations, probably because they try to teach about more complex cases... any recommended one for my simple case?